# jquery animate - dead simple

Tags: jquery

All I want to do is on `.click()` is `.animate #slip`, essentially Im changing the css at the moment from `top: 10px to top: 0px`

Instead of it being quite clunky i'd like to animate the movement on the change of CSS.

Currently use .toggleClass to achieve this:

```
    $("#div1").click(function() {
        $("#div2t").toggleClass('min');
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate like this:

```
$(selector).click(function() {
  $("#slip").animate({ top: 0; });
});
```

Unless you need the `.animate` container, leave it off...the ID selector is, well, as fast as it gets :)

If you wanted the click to animate it back every other `click` as well, use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
$(selector).toggle(function() {
  $("#slip").animate({ top: 0; });
}, function() {
  $("#slip").animate({ top: 10; });
});
```

Comment: @David - `.slideUp()`/`.slideDown()` **hide** and **show** the element, not re-position it, they serve a different purpose.  If you wanted that effect, I still wouldn't use those :) ...because there's `.slideToggle()` as well.

Comment: oh yah. duh...i should NOT be posting on SO early in the morning...i need some caffeine. haha.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
#CSS:
.animate #slip {
    top: 10px;
}

#JS
$("element").click(function() {
    $(".animate #slip").animate({ top: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").click(function(){
$("#div2t").animate({"top":"0px"},"slow");
);
```

Where slow is the speed , you can put it fast or time in milliseconds without ""